# Does gaussian_filter1d not work well in higher orders?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, filtering, gaussian

Ok, so what I'm trying to do is a scale space on a 1D set of data where the entire data set presumably is taken from a sum of gaussians function. To do this, I have to apply a gaussian convolution to the data set. My end goal is to find the number of gaussians in this data set by the number of zero crossings in the second order derivative of the convoluted data. The reasons for this come from [this article](http://cecs.wright.edu/~agoshtas/GMIP94.pdf).

Now the problem occurs with `scipy`'s `gaussian_filter1d` that I'm using to do the convolution. I assume that when it says filter it only means a convolution with a gaussian because there is already a separate function for fourier_gaussian_filter. In addition, to avoid approximation, I'm using the `gaussian_filter1d`'s own 2nd order derivative and then apply the convolution. The problem occurs when I keep lowering the sigma of the gaussian filter that you would assume that it would act more like an dirac delta. And this is what actually occurs at smaller values of sigma in the zero order derivate. Unfortunately, when I apply a 2nd order derivate gaussian filter, the data does not have the zero-crossings that I expect it to. In fact, it doesn't have any zero crossings even when there is only one gaussian in the original data.

Some possible ideas that came to me about what could be the problem is that an actual delta function doesn't have a derivative and that the derivative of a really small sigma Gaussian can't approximate the derivative of a delta. But I wanted to hear the community's thoughts on the problem. Thank you for reading this post.

Comment: Is this mainly a programming question?

Comment: This is mainly a question to understand a possible problem with the gaussian filter. But you could call it a mix of understanding what the function does and if it is possible to approximate the mathematical behavior properly.

Comment: right, this may not be the best Stack Exchange to ask this question, that's all I'm concerned about - simply because not many people here will know what a `dirac delta` is, for example, so you may not get an answer here. Maybe try this as well: http://math.stackexchange.com/ I'm pretty sure that you'll get some good answers there. Another option is to look into the implementation of `gaussian_filter1d` and the functions it's coupled with.